# One round fella

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Big and chubby, I like to float
>    Lots of parasites are on my boat;
>    I feel a bit lonely, even my friends aren't fine
>    You see: we are now eight, but used to be nine;
>    More than tea I would rather drink milk
>    If you pay attention you'll see, it's all around me.

What am I?

Comment: Glad to see no one comes here commenting its actually flat not round =D

Comment: @Alex Well, now that you mention it...    ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are :

> Earth

Because :
*Big and chubby, i like to float*

> It floats in space

*lots of parasites are on my boat;*

> All life is a parasite of our planet

*I feel a bit lonely, even my friends aren't fine*
*you see: we are now eight, but used to be nine;*

> Pluto is no longer a planet but a dwarf planet

*More than tea i would rather drink milk*
*if you pay attention you'll see, it's all around me.*

> Solar system is within the Milky Way

Comment: well, that was quick

Comment: @Midori One of the verse was a _huge_ hint :) But it is a nice riddle!

Comment: Was it the 9 -> 8 bit,  @Saeïdryl ? Nice answer,  btw.

Comment: @Saeïdryl yep, i've deleted it since you got the right answer!

Comment: @Midori I think you can wait some time before accepting my answer (like 24h to give a chance to everyone around... the globe), maybe someone will post a fitting or really funny answer too :)